# With this lens and mirror combination, should there be a third image formed?

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

[image]

With this lens and mirror combination, should the lens form a third image after the second image got reflected by the mirror as shown below?

I saw a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/aGHnH_4KFRE) answering the same problem, yet i'm still unconvinced that there wasn't any third image coming out like the video shown. Any explanation would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What part of the ray diagram did you not understand?

Comment: @Sam The video that i saw doesn't show any third image formed like my diagram does. Is the diagram that i draw wrong?

Comment: The people here do not know what you know or what you watched. Please provide some context to support your question. See How to ask a good question-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Where is mirror.

Comment: I can see only two lenses.

Comment: @YuvrajSingh... The lens on the right side of the image is actually a concave mirror. The green rays can be seen being reflected by the mirror. Sorry for the vague diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram in the video and your diagram are not quite equivalent.  In the video, the lens forms a first image *beyond* the concave mirror, while in your diagram, the lens forms a first (real) image *before* the concave mirror.  Also in the video, the concave mirror forms second image on the left side of the lens, while in your diagram the concave mirror forms a second (real) image on the right side of the lens.  Finally, in the video the lens would then form a third (virtual) image on the *right* side of the lens, while in your diagram the lens would form a third (real) image on the *left* side of the lens.

So, you are right: in *your* diagram, there will be three real images formed.